# Deleting a row by column value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to delete a row by targeting a column value?

For instance take a look at this image

[image]

Let's say the email address under the column *Email* in the first row is jdoe@gmail.com.

Could I delete that row by targeting that email address?

Something to the effect of...

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Users
WHERE Email = jdoe@gmail.com;
```

Would I need to specify the database?

Comment: you dont need to specify database ,if you are in same database.

Comment: well, definitely always use a predicate in your DELETE statement. Otherwise, the ENTIRE table gets deleted. Perhaps OP needs to revisit `Relational Data` concepts again.

Comment: What's wrong with a bit of trial  and error? Create a table, enter some data, and try to delete it.

Comment: yes - put quotes around string - in SQL management studio try.....USE [yourdatabase];DELETE FROM dbo.Users
WHERE Email='jdoe@gmail.com'

Comment: @brano, why are you asking this question at all? what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I want to delete a user since there is no way to delete the user from the front-end. I am helping out someone with their website that was built by someone else years ago. I don't really know Microsoft SQL, but I figured it should be easy enough to delete a specific user this way/

Comment: also possible.....DELETE FROM [yourdatabase].dbo.Users WHERE Email='jdoe@gmail.com';

Comment: @Ivan Starostin he's asking to find out how to do it.  He has the problem he wants to delete a record - I dunno, a bit like someone who isn't a  mechanic might want to help change some car oil - as an analogy.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton Basically lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Be aware that any record with that email be deleted.  You also need ' around your string -> `Email='jdoe@gmail.com'`

You only need to specify the database if you are executing from a different database than the table you are targeting.